# Can I use an HTML button to execute a PyScript REPL?

Tags: pyscript

There used to be a green 'play' button that was displayed at the bottom of a PyScript REPL element. This seems to have disappeared and the only option to execute the code is shift-enter.

Can I execute the code in the REPL by any other means, ideally via an HTML button?

I included a REPL in my code and the result did not show the execute button.

Comment: What version of PyScript are you using? Did you include the pyscript CSS as well?

Comment: I'm using the 'latest' and yes am including the CSS as well, i.e.
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

Comment: The play button typically only appears on mouse hover. You can override the `:hover` styles in pyscript.css to make it appear all the time.

Comment: OK, thanks. I set the default opacity in .py-repl-run-button to 1 instead of 0 and the button always shows - which is fine for what I want. It's odd that the hover style appears not to work though.
Anyway, thanks for pointing out that this is a CSS problem - that was a real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, not exactly solved but Jeff Glass has explained, in the comments, that this is a CSS issue and I've solved my particular problem by setting the default opacity of the button to 1 (opaque). This makes the button show up all the time. I.e. I put this in the HTML head.

```
<style>
    .py-repl-run-button {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

I'm still not sure why the hover style doesn't work.